# Migrate Access Web App to Desktop Database

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, ms-office, office365

We have a MS Access Web App hosted on Sharepoint Online. Now we need to discontinue this Web app and convert it to an Access Desktop Database.

What would be the general steps to make this and avoid having to recreate everything from scratch?

Igor.

Answer (score 0):

There is none. It is a complete rewrite.